# SSRS Combination Pie Chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I have created a combination chart in excel which I am attempting to replicate within SSRS.

The chart shows three versions of 'success' plus the percentage 'failed'.  (Please see image for more detail)

For one of the segments, i.e. success v2, I would like to then break this data down by how long it took to achieve success, as a percentage.

I've attempted changing my chart type a few times within SSRS and exploring the chart 'General Custom Attributes' however I haven't been able to get very far with figuring out how to link two pie/donut charts...your help would be invaluable!

Thanks

Charlotte

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

This isn't really an answer but a list of things to look at/consider and too long to fit in a comment.

You need to look at the `Chart Series` properties, in particular the Custom Attributes related to 'Collected...'

[image]

This allows you to explode a section but as far as I know it only allows you to use values or a % lower than a specified threshold, not a particular section as you want. This migh work if the section you want to explode out is always the smallest but I guess you cannot guarantee that.

You might be able to get round this by adding another column to your dataset that always shows a high number for 'failure' and 'success x1' and a small number for 'success x2' but i'm not sure if you can define which field to explode on and visualise a different field, otherwise your main pie would look incorrect.

Alternatively you could just show two charts.

Comment: Thanks for your message Alan. I had a play with the chart series collected properties however, as you mentioned, you cannot pick and choose which segment of the chart you would like to explode. In the end I decided to create two charts, but this works well!